# How to separate everything inside my sqlite database

Tags: python, sql, arrays, sqlite, select

i have a database which has two thing in my database, name of a fruit and how long is it in the freezer.

when i use

```
cur1.execute("""SELECT fruit_name, freeze_time,
                        COUNT (*) AS total_fruit
                        FROM fruit_page
                        GROUP BY fruit_name, freeze_days""")

rows = cur1.fetchall()
```

rows will actually show the name of the fruit, time in freezer and the amount of fruit in batch

```
[('Apple', '2', 2)('Banana','1',2)('Banana','2',1)]
```

How do i separate this, so that

```
[('Apple', '2', 1)('Apple', '2', 1)('Banana','1',1)('Banana','1',1)('Banana','2',1)]
```

Or at least tell me how do i make a list that can contain two same integer in it so when i have 2 piece of apple that is two days in freezer, when i call

```
for i in range(len(rows))
   if fruit_name == apple;
      basket.append(rows[i][1)
```

it will print actually print [2, 2] not just 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is all the rows of the table with the columns `fruit_name` and `freeze_time` and a 3d column with the value 1:

```
SELECT fruit_name, 
       freeze_time, 
       1 AS columnname -- change the alias of this column
FROM fruit_page
```